# Passing a two-dimensional array for threaded processing

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, pthreads

K and THREADS are arbitrarily defined as follows:

```
#define K 1000
#define THREADS 2
```

Let's say I'm responsible for doing some stuff with a two-dimensional array called:

```
long A[K][K];
```

I need to pass this, as well as an integer, to a number of threaded instances of a function, so I make this struct:

```
typedef struct tdata {
    long *(*C)[K];
    int nt;
} tdata;
```

I then follow standard procedure for starting POSIX threads and do the following:

```
void threader(long A[K][K]) {    
    pthread_t p[THREADS];
    tdata d[THREADS];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<THREADS;++i) {
        d[i].nt = i;
        d[i].C = &A;
        pthread_create(&p[i],NULL,func,&d[i]);
        pthread_join(p[i],NULL);
    }
}
```

And then in my function, I attempt to access the aforementioned array as follows:

```
void *func(void *arg) {
   tdata *data=arg;
   int a, b;
   ...
   for(a=0; a<K; ++a)
      for(b=0; b<K; ++b)
         long access = (*(data->C))[a][b];
   ...
   return 0; 
}
```

What happens is I end up retrieving a few wonky numbers before the program seg faults and dies. My suspicion is that I'm doing something very wrong in regards to passing my array to func. Can anyone give me a clue as to what I should be doing with A[K][K]?

Comment: There's no `G` in `tdata`. Please show us your *actual* code.

Comment: Is `A` a local (automatic) variable? If so, it's out of scope after its enclosing function returns...

Comment: `long *(*A)[K];` should be `long (*A)[K];` and you should access it `data->A[a][b]`.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, A is an array that is passed to the function that is creating the threads; that function must then pass it onto the func function that does work using A.

Comment: @cnicutar I tried that earlier but the program still seg faults.

Comment: I've clarified that the "threader" is its own function above now.
main calls threader, which then creates threads of func.

Comment: Compile your program under debug (-g), set `ulimit -c unlimited`, run your program to get a core dump. Debug with `gdb program-name core*` and use the `bt` command (backtrace) to get an idea where it is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned by cnicutar in a comment above, `long *(*C)[K];` should indeed be `long (*C)[K];` and accessed using `data->C[a][b]` rather than `(*(data->C))[a][b]`.

Additionally, I also had to change `d[i].C = &A;` to `d[i].C = A;` in `threader`, which I did, and now the program functions correctly.